# No column name returned - is there way to return a column name?

Tags: sql-server

Using Microsoft SQL Server. Running a stored procedure that returns 'No column name' as the column name.

Is there a way to see what this column name is?  Or to have the stored procedure return a column name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an alias in your stored procedure to give a name to the column.

Ex:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMaxPrc]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(TOTAL) AS TOTAL 
    FROM MYTABLE -- it will return TOTAL instead of NoColumnName
END
```

If you don't specify the alias it will return `nocolumnname`

Comment: Note that this is only required for calculated columns and not things you are returning directly from the table. Also, the name you give your calculated column is arbitrary. You can name it anything as long as it follows normal column naming conventions and doesn't conflict with another column in your `SELECT`

Answer (score 3):

select the unknown vaue using "as"

ex. count(salary) as totalsalary